# C++ math not producing correct output

Tags: c++

Why does this algorithm not produce a triangle output in C++ when it should?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double w = 1050;
   double a = 1050*3;
   double speed;
   for(int x = 0; x <= 1050; x+=42)
   {
       speed = 42*((4*a)/w*abs((fmod((x-w/2),w))-w/2)*-1+w)/w;
       cout << "x: " << x << " speed: " << speed << endl;
   }
}
```

Produces:

```
x: 0 speed: -462
x: 42 speed: -441.84
x: 84 speed: -421.68
x: 126 speed: -401.52
x: 168 speed: -381.36
x: 210 speed: -361.2
x: 252 speed: -341.04
x: 294 speed: -320.88
x: 336 speed: -300.72
x: 378 speed: -280.56
x: 420 speed: -260.4
x: 462 speed: -240.24
x: 504 speed: -220.08
x: 546 speed: -199.92
x: 588 speed: -179.76
x: 630 speed: -159.6
x: 672 speed: -139.44
x: 714 speed: -119.28
x: 756 speed: -99.12
x: 798 speed: -78.96
x: 840 speed: -58.8
x: 882 speed: -38.64
x: 924 speed: -18.48
x: 966 speed: 1.68
x: 1008 speed: 21.84
x: 1050 speed: 42
```

https://rextester.com/NSI24628

The correct answer is
[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XiUgHs7QYOWqggjLup0Wsx-eo0R82xrelUTTDBlgNkE/edit?usp=sharing

Why is C++ producing a linear answer whereas a triangle function is expected?

Comment: You just posted this.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes but it was closed unfairly. It was closed because they thought this was a duplicate of int to double narrowing conversion but this is nothing like that. I edited it later but the admins wouldn't reopen it

Comment: Simply put because the fmod function doesn't not behave in the same way as the MOD function in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Your formula clearly expects the result of `fmod((x-w/2),w)` to be in the range `[0,w)` but it isn't, it's in the range `(-w,w)`, so you get different results. I believe this was explained to you in the previous quesiton.

Comment: You might have more luck with `fmod((x+w/2),w)`

Comment: @john thank you very much. That cleared it up and explained it. If you put it in an answer I can accept the answer

Comment: With such a simple program, this would have been the perfect opportunity to start learning to think like a programmer, with some exploratory _"why does this not behave the way I expect"_ thinking.  By breaking the parts of the equation down and looking at their value, you would have quickly identified that `fmod` is not behaving the way you expect.  And you could have then corrected it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula expects the result of `fmod((x-w/2),w)` to be in the range `[0,w)` but it isn't. The actual range is `(-w,w)`. If `(x-w/2)` is negative then the result of `fmod` will be negaitve.

The simple fix is to replace `fmod((x-w/2),w)` with `fmod((x+w/2),w)` which ensures the first parameter of `fmod` is positive without changing the overall effect.